# Partition a list into equivalence classes

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am trying to write a function in SML which when given a list of general elements, reorders its elements into equivalent classes and returns a list of these classes (type "a list list).
Leave the elements in the classes in the same order as in the original list. 
A given function defines the equivalence of the elements and it returns true if the elements are equivalent or false otherwise. 
I cannot seem to get a grip on the solution.

```
fun sample x y = x = y
```

Required type: *fn : (''a -> ''a -> bool) -> ''a list -> ''a list list*

Thank you very much for the help.

The helper function does not work correctly, all I want to do with it is see if a given element belongs to any of the classes and put it accordingly inside or create a new sublist which contains it.

```
fun srt listoflists func new = 
        case listoflists of [] => [[]]
         |  a::b => if func (new, hd a) = true then (new::a)::b
                    else if func (new, hd a) = false then a::(srt b func new) else [new]::a::b
```

The sample functions checks equivalence of two elements when divided by 11.

Tests are not all working, it is not adding 17 into a new class.

```
 srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] eq 7;
val it = [[7,7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] : int list list
- srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] eq 5;
val it = [[7,7,7],[5,5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] : int list list
- srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] eq 11;
val it = [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11,11],[13,13,13]] : int list list
- srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] eq 13;
val it = [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13,13]] : int list list
- srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13]] eq 17;
val it = [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13],[]] : int list list
- srt [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13],[111,111,111]] eq 111;
val it = [[7,7,7],[5,5,5],[11,11,11],[13,13,13],[111,111,111,111]]
```

How to correct this and also once this helper function works, how to encorporate it exactly into the main function that is required.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide a list of a few concrete examples of input and desired output?

Comment: You could start by writing a helper function, one which takes a list of lists and a new element, as well as the Boolean-valued function, and either appends the new element to the appropriate list in the list of lists (if it is equivalent to the elements in one of those lists) or starts a new list containing just that item, and adds this new list to the list of lists. For efficiency, append the new item to the *front* of the list and have the overall function reverse the lists (using the built-in `rev`) before returning them.

Comment: Thank you John. I have tried to come up with a solution for the helper function but it is not working right.

Comment: @JohnColeman I updated the question with what I have tried as you instructed, thank you.

Comment: @KevinJohnson the function takes a list of general elements (of any type, but which can be compared) and on the basis of the sample function given above which takes two elements and sees if they are equivalent (returns true or false regarding some condition) rearranges that first list into a list of lists which contains elements that represent equivalent classes of the original elements. It then returns a list of lists which are the equivalence classes (the order of the elements is kept).

Answer (score 1):

Your example code seems like you are getting close, but has several issues

1) The basis cases is where `new` should be added, so in that case you should return the value `[[new]]` rather than `[[]]`

2) Your problem description suggests that `func` be of type `''a -> ''a -> bool` but your code for `srt` seems to be assuming it is of type `(''a * ''a) -> bool`. Rather than subexpressions like `func (new, hd a)` you need `func new (hd a)`  (note the parentheses location).

3) if `func` returns a `bool` then comparing the output to `true` is needlessly verbose, instead of `if func new (hd a) = true then ...` simply have `if func new (hd a) then ...`

4) Since you are adding `[new]` in the basis cases, your second clause is needlessly verbose. I see no reason to have any *nested* `if` expressions.

Since this seems to be homework, I don't want to say much more. Once you get the helper working correctly it should be fairly straightforward to use it (in the recursive case) of the overall function. Note that you could use `(a @ [new])::b` rather than `(new::a)::b` if you want to avoid the need for a final mapping of `rev` across the final return value. `@` is more expensive than `::` (it is `O(n)` rather than `O(1)`), but for small examples it really doesn't matter and could even be slightly better since it would avoid the final step of reversing the lists.