# creating a list of lists based on another list content

Tags: sml

I have 2 lists. They will always be the same length with respect to each other and might look like this toy example. The actual content is not predictable.

```
val original = [1,   2,  0,  1,  1,  2]
val elements = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

I want to create the following list:

```
val mappedList = [["c"],["a","d","e"],["b","f"]]
                    0         1           2
```

So the pattern is to group elements in the elements list, based on the value of the same-position element in original list. Any idea how can I achieve this in SML? I am not looking for a hard coded solution for this  exact data, but a general one.

Comment: What does not work as expected?

Comment: The process of creating a smart approach.

Comment: This looks much like [Partition a list into equivalence classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577169/partition-a-list-into-equivalence-classes) answered ten days ago. Call `ListPair.zip` on your two lists and group pairs by an equivalence function that only regards the number. You may also get inspired by Haskell's [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) / [`groupBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy), although the source code might be a little hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to first write a function which takes an ordered pair such as `(2,"c")` and a list of ordered pairs such as

```
[(3,["a"]),(2,["b"]),(1,["a","e"])]
```

and returns a modified list with the element tacked onto the appropriate list (or creates a new (key,list) pair if none exists) so that the result would look like:

```
[(3,["a"]),(2,["c","b"]),(1,["a","e"])]
```

The following function does the trick:

```
fun store ((k,v), []) = [(k,[v])]
|   store ((k,v), (m,vs)::items) = if k = m 
        then (m,v::vs)::items 
        else (m,vs)::store ((k,v) ,items);
```

Given a list of keys and a corresponding list of values, you could fold this last function over the corresponding zip of the keys and values:

```
fun group ks vs = foldl store [] (ListPair.zip(ks,vs));
```

For example, if

```
val original = [1,   2,  0,  1,  1,  2];
val elements = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

- group original elements;
val it = [(1,["e","d","a"]),(2,["f","b"]),(0,["c"])] : (int * string list) list
```

Note that you could sort this list according to the keys if so desired.

Finally -- if you just want the groups (reversed to match their original order in the list) the following works:

```
fun groups ks vs = map rev (#2 (ListPair.unzip (group ks vs)));
```

For example,

```
- groups original elements;
val it = [["a","d","e"],["b","f"],["c"]] : string list list
```

**On Edit**: if you want the final answer to be sorted according to the keys (as opposed to the order in which they appear) you could use @SimonShine 's idea and store the data in sorted order, or you could sort the output of the `group` function. Somewhat oddly, the SML Standard Basis Library [lacks a built-in sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14412749/4996248), but the standard implementations have their own sorts (and it is easy enough to write your own). For example, using SML/NJ's sort you could write:

```
fun sortedGroups ks vs =
    let 
        val g = group ks vs
        val s = ListMergeSort.sort (fn ((i,_),(j,_)) => i>j) g
    in
        map rev (#2 (ListPair.unzip s))
    end;
```

Leading to the expected:

```
- sortedGroups original elements;
val it = [["c"],["a","d","e"],["b","f"]] : string list list
```

Comment: It seems that keys are assumed to be integers, rather than `''a` and that they should be ordered from low to high, from the example at least.

Comment: @SimonShine  Good point. Since your answer adequately addresses the sorting issue and OP might need information about the order of appearance, I'll leave my basic answer the same, although you inspired me to say a bit more about how to sort the output of `group`.

Comment: Right, I thought about sorting it in the end, but this applies better to the code you've already given. :)

Answer (score 2):

With the general strategy to first form a list of pairs `(k, vs)` where `k` is the value they are grouped by and `vs` is the elements, one could then extract the elements alone. Since John did this, I'll add two other things you can do:

1. Assume that `original : int list`, insert the pairs in sorted order:

   ```
   fun group ks vs =
       let fun insert ((k, v), []) = [(k, [v])]
             | insert (k1v as (k1, v), items as ((k2vs as (k2, vs))::rest)) =
                 case Int.compare (k1, k2) of
                      LESS => (k1, [v]) :: items
                    | EQUAL => (k2, v::vs) :: rest
                    | GREATER => k2vs :: insert (k1v, rest)
           fun extract (k, vs) = rev vs
       in
         map extract (List.foldl insert [] (ListPair.zip (ks, vs)))
       end
   ```

   This produces the same result as your example:

   ```
   - val mappedList = group original elements;
   > val mappedList = [["c"], ["a", "d", "e"], ["b", "f"]] : string list list
   ```

   I'm a bit unsure if by "The actual content is not predictable." you also mean "The *types* of `original` and `elements` are not known." So:

   Assume that `original : 'a list` and that some `cmp : 'a * 'a -> order` exists:

   ```
   fun group cmp ks vs =
       let fun insert ((k, v), []) = [(k, [v])]
             | insert (k1v as (k1, v), items as ((k2vs as (k2, vs))::rest)) =
                 case cmp (k1, k2) of
                      LESS => (k1, [v]) :: items
                    | EQUAL => (k2, v::vs) :: rest
                    | GREATER => k2vs :: insert (k1v, rest)
           fun extract (k, vs) = rev vs
       in
         map extract (List.foldl insert [] (ListPair.zip (ks, vs)))
       end
   ```
2. Use a tree for storing pairs:

   ```
   datatype 'a bintree = Empty | Node of 'a bintree * 'a * 'a bintree

   (* post-order tree folding *)
   fun fold f e Empty = e
     | fold f e0 (Node (left, x, right)) =
       let val e1 = fold f e0 right
           val e2 = f (x, e1)
           val e3 = fold f e2 left
       in e3 end

   fun group cmp ks vs =
       let fun insert ((k, v), Empty) = Node (Empty, (k, [v]), Empty)
             | insert (k1v as (k1, v), Node (left, k2vs as (k2, vs), right)) =
                 case cmp (k1, k2) of
                      LESS => Node (insert (k1v, left), k2vs, right)
                    | EQUAL => Node (left, (k2, v::vs), right)
                    | GREATER => Node (left, k2vs, insert (k1v, right))
           fun extract ((k, vs), result) = rev vs :: result
       in
         fold extract [] (List.foldl insert Empty (ListPair.zip (ks, vs)))
       end
   ```